# Reactive effect on button click does not execute functions on Shiny Python

Tags: python, py-shiny

I'm trying to execute a function inside a reactive effect linked to an action button.
All the log prints get printed on click but any function invoked inside the reactive effect does not execute.

The form I'm using is in a modal. I tested by printing the inputs from the form then closing the modal but no success.

Button declaration :

```
ui.input_action_button(id='create_score_button',label='Créer', class_="btn-success")
```

Reactive effect :

```
@reactive.Effect
@reactive.event(input.create_score_button, ignore_none=True)
def insert_score():
    
    print("button is clicked with user input :")
    print(str(input.score_name()))
    print(str(input.score_description()))
    print(str(input.score_learning_data_name()))
    print(str(input.score_resp_var()))
    print(str(input.score_id_var()))
    print(str(input.f_reapprentissage_score()))
    print(str(input.freq_reapp()))
    print(str(input.freq_labels()))
    print(str(input.score_relearning_time_H()))
    print(str(input.score_relearning_time_M()))
    
    ui.modal_remove("score_creation")
```

Behaviour :
[image]